# How is this solution of Dirichlet Integral wrong?

Tags: calculus, analysis

I tried to find a new way to solve Dirichlet Integral but faild and I wonder how. For Dirichlet Integral $$\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{sinx}{x} dx.$$ According to Euler's formula, we have

$$\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{sinx}{x} dx = \int\limits_0^\infty \frac{exp(ix)-exp(-ix)}{2ix}dx = (t=ix) \frac{1}{i}\int\limits_0^{-\infty *i}\frac{exp(t)-exp(-t)}{t}dt.$$

Where the symbol $-\infty *i$ might mean the $-\infty$ position of the imaginary axis. But observe that the integral
$$\int\limits_0^{-\infty}\frac{exp(t)-exp(-t)}{t}dt$$
is not convergent.

Comment: Do not blindly apply results you have seen for integrals of real valued functions over intervals in the real line to the complex case.

Comment: Remember, $t$ is imaginary in your final integral, so we can still bound the modulus and show that the integral converges

Comment: Use ```\sin```, ```\exp``` for better formatting.